# multiple rows selection for pickerview in swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

I want to select a multiple rows in pickerview in swift
 this is for single row selection

`import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

```
@IBOutlet weak var titlelabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView!
var cars = ["benz","audi","lombagini","rangerrover","bently"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    pickerview.delegate = self
    pickerview.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return cars.count

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    return cars[row]

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    titlelabel.text = cars[row]
}
```

}`

did any one have any idea to select multiple rows in picker view

in objective-c AlPickerview but it is not working.

Comment: So did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if component == 0{
       return bloodgroup.count
    }
    else if component == 1 {
       return districk.count
    }
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0{
        return bloodgroup[row]
    }
    else if component == 1 {
        return districk[row]
    }
   return ""

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == 0{
        print(bloodgroup[row])
    }
    else if component == 1 {
        print(districk[row])
    }

}
```

Comment: Add some explanation.